# Move Emails Easily Using Search - Outlook 2011 Feature on the MAC for Outlook 2010 Windows

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search

My main email client is *Outlook 2010 for Windows 7*. I also have a Mac but I do not use it that much however on the MAC you have *Outlook 2011.*

In my *Outlook 2010* for Windows 7, I have many folders. There is one feature I would like to know if it is available or something similar which is on *Outlook 2011* for the Mac.

On the *Outlook 2011* for the Mac you can go to: `Top Menu > Message > Move > Choose Folder` or press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

This bring up a box where you can just type the beginning part of the folder and all the folders with that beginning appears (To search), you select the one you want and the selected emails move to that folder.

I hope I have explained it well.

Does anyone know if there is a plugin on Outlook 2010 or may I have just missed the function.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried Shift-Ctrl-M?  Checking the help document also might help.

Comment: @Ramhound CTRL+SHIFT+M creates a new message. CTL+SHIFT+V is to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Superuser. If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, this is available to you in Outlook 2010.

With the message(s) you want to move selected, you can use the *"MOVE"* button on the Home Ribbon which will show you a list of folders or choose *"Other Folder"*. This brings up a list of folders available to move it to. You can type the first letter of the folder name you want to move it to in order to jump down the list.

This can also be achieved by *"RIGHT"* clicking on the message(s) you want to move and choosing from the pop-up menu.

FYI; here is a list of Outlook [keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-outlook-2010-HP010354403.aspx). "MOVE" is among them. It is <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot search the folder name?

Comment: You didn't say anything about searching by folder name. You might want to add that to your question.

Comment: I did " This bring up a box where you can just type the beginning part of the folder and all the folders with that beginning appear, you select the one you want and the selected emails move to that folder. "

Comment: Any update with this please?

Comment: No. Sorry. I am thinking you are seeing the difference between OS functionality and the versions of Outlook. I've not been able to get Outlook 2010 do as the MAC version does as you described.

Comment: Ok, it would be such a great feature to have. If anyone knows of a plugin, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add the move to another folder option is to right click the button in the ribbon and, "Add to Quick Access Toolbar".  As a note, I did this, but then you can't use the first letter of the folder to "jump".

The solution for this (which I discovered with the help of this article) is to add the "Other Folders" (a sub menu of "move") option to the quick access toolbar instead.  I have it as the first item, so now I press alt+1 and then the first letter of the folder.